# Dynamically Generated delete button

Tags: php, html

I'm new to php and I was wondering how I would be able to create something like a delete button for deleting items in a list that would be generated from a dynamically growing array.

An example of what I mean is this:

```
<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['foo']))
{
    if (isset($_SESSION['words']))
    {
        $_SESSION['words'][] = 'added word';
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['words'] = array('cat', 'dog', 'you', 'me');
    }

    foreach ($_SESSION['words'] as $key => &$value)
    {
        echo "<p>" . 
             $value . 
             " - <input type='submit' name='delete_" . 
             $value . 
             "' value='Delete Entry' /></p>";
    }

    if (isset($_REQUEST['clear']))
    {
        session_destroy();
    }
?>
```

Where, on every button click that gets sent to my script it would echo out the array with the buttons.

I'd like to link the delete buttons to a function that looked something like:

```
function delete_entry( $index )
{
    unset($_SESSION['words'][$index]);
    $_SESSION['words'] = array_values($_SESSION['words']);
}
```

Is what I'm asking even possible?

Comment: I read over this a couple times and don't really know what your actual goal is. Specifically why you would use sessions to handle this. What is the user actually doing here? If we know that we might be able to suggest an approach. As it stands, I can't think of a real case web scenario where the code posted would make a whole lot of sense

Comment: That was just a quick example I guess I didn't illustrate it so well. Basically there would be a form that the user would enter ID numbers in to and hit a button that would add those IDs to the list. I'm looking for a way to generate delete buttons with each entry from that list, which would be an array, and link those delete buttons with the index of their respective entries.

Comment: are these id numbers stored in a database? Or in some way shared with other users?

Comment: they would be stored in a session array variable such as the one above

Comment: I'm asking if they NEED to be accessible by other users. To me it doesn't make sense to have a list stored in a session for one user. The session could expire while they're in the bathroom, for example. So by asking if they're stored in a database or need to be accessed by other users it's like asking what exactly the list is and what one is expected to be doing with it. The answer to that determines how one might handle the basic problem. I would only use session if the data was not important at all and wouldn't anger someone if the session expired unexpectedly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array of words seem to be stored in your session variable, so I'm assuming that you want to remove/add words to it. How about this...?

1. Have a separate form for each word with a hidden field saying what the word is:

   So in the for loop:
   `echo "<form><p>".$value." - <input type='submit' value='Delete Entry' /></p><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"delword\" value=\"".$value."\"/></form>";`
2. `if(isset[$_REQUEST['delword']])` remove it from the session array (do this *before* you do your echoing for loop. (You could use [array_search](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) to find the element, then run unset as you suggested)

Let me know if you want me to elaborate on this suggestion.

Comment: I tried what you suggested and that seems to be on the right track. However, I'm confused as to how I get the $value from the hidden field in my php script

Comment: That's it! I've got it working now. Thanks for your patience Kai Qing and shadow, I really appreciate it

Comment: no problem. My nonstop questioning isn't to be a bastard, but to make sure you're coding in a sane way. You say you're new to PHP so you might not be aware of many many different and much easier ways to achieve this same thing without having to refresh the page or rely on sessions, etc.